# Python : Variable in a different module doesn't get changed

Tags: python, django, module

I have having issues with updating variables in one module from another module. I'll put it in the simplest way possible.

### mymod.py

```
params= { "name" : "system_user" }
```

### config.py

```
import myapp.mymod

myapp.mymod.params={}
```

However, the **mymod.py** remains unchanged.

Say if i try ,

```
myapp.mymod.params["name"]="oracle"
```

Even then the original .py file remains unchanged. 
Is there any way **at all** to achieve that?

**Update**: Right after posting the question, I realized how evil the feature could be, if present.

So I shall reframe my question and request suggestions for the same. I need to update a python module variable data so that another module is able to access the refreshed data.

One solution that comes to my mind is to add a static properties file which would used to re-fresh all the dictionary data in the python module.
Thanks,
Shoubhik

Comment: did you expect source code to change because of change in runtime?

Comment: Yes, Is there any way to say " Hey change the source file and regenerate the .pyc " ? I'm sorry if I sound dumb. Just asking! I'm making sure that the module is being loaded from the .py and not the .pyc

Comment: Sorry, it's just not the way it works. Runtime changes affect only runtime, not the original source.

Comment: If you want to make sure the module is being loaded from the .py file, delete the .pyc file before you run it.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. So, can the .pyc file be changed for good? So that all future references find the same updated value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning a new value to the "params" name, but any existing references to the original dictionary will remain unchanged.

myapp.mymod.params.clear() will probably update all other references since it doesn't reassign a new value to the "params" name but changes it in stead.

E.g.

```
>>> x = {"foo":"bar"}
>>> a = x
>>> x = {}
>>> print a
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

versus

```
>>> x = {"foo": "bar"}
>>> a = x
>>> x.clear()
>>> print a
{}
```